# Как узнать размер HTML страницы до ее загрузки?

Tags: java, android

Создать загрузчик html-страницы в файл. Требуется получить размер страницы до ее скачивания — для реализации индикатора прогресса загрузки с использованием `AsyncTask`, то есть требуется скачать HTML страницу с индикатором прогресса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456727/Как-узнать-размер-html-страницы-до-ее-загрузки");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
```

Дальше так:

```
int size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Или так:

```
String contentLengthStr=urlConnection.getHeaderField("content-length");
```

Если не вдаваться в реализацию - нужно отправить HEAD запрос на нужный URL, и из ответа на этот запрос извлечь значение хедера `content-length`

**EDIT**
У вашей ссылки есть хедер

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

То есть получить размер - никак.

Comment: int size = urlConnection.getContentLength(); - выдает "-1"

Comment: String contentLengthStr=urlConnection.getHeaderField("content-length"); - возвращает "null"

Comment: @SmallSani, ссылку в студию!

Comment: Если там chunked, то логично.

Answer (score 0):

В заголовках ответа посмотреть заголовок Content-Length, если он есть. Если его нет, то никак.

Посылать head-запрос бессмысленно, поскольку заголовки будут те же, что у get - просто получится два запроса вместо одного.